# How to store the seekbar values in a global variable use in another screen

Tags: android

Hi I am try to write a code in android where I have a 2 seekbars and I want to store the values obtained from seekbars and would like to use it in another screen. So can any help me how to do it. 
I am using global variables because I want store the values untill the I store I reuse them. 
Here is my code so please any one tell me how to do that.

```
package com.example.newairways;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;



public class relationship extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private String Q1a,Q1b;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar1, mSeekBar2;
    private TextView tv1, tv2;
    private Button ok,nextQ,cancel;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    Intent myIntent;
    //List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs= null;
    Bundle myValues;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relationships);
        myValues=getIntent().getExtras();
        mSeekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Q1a); 
        mSeekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mSeekBar2= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Q1b); 
        mSeekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ans1a);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ans1b);

       TextView welcomeMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
        welcomeMsg.setText("name : "+myValues.getString("value"));

           ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
            nextQ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextquestion);
            cancel= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);              

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        switch (seekBar.getId())
        {

        case R.id.Q1a:

            tv1.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%") ;
            Toast.makeText(relationship.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

case R.id.Q1b:
    tv2.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%") ;
            Toast.makeText(relationship.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        } 
    }






    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Go with shared preferences.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file GlobalVars.java:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {

    private static String value2;

    public static String getSeekBarValue() {
        return value2;
    }

    public static void setSeekBarValue(String value) {
        value2 = value;
    }

}
```

Then in your files you can save and load your variables:

```
GlobalVars.setSeekBarValue(progress);
int v = GlobalVars.getSeekBarValue();
```

You asked for global variables but don't forget that the values they store are deleted every time you exit the app.